# Can Java Garbage Collector (GC) collectable for hierarchical object structure?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, hierarchical-trees

In the following class hierarchical structure, 

I set null to **parent** and **child**. 

I'm not sure whether Garbage Collector can collect or not after parent has been set as **null** and **child** has been set as **null**.

(Assuming that **main** method is inside a class.)

```
public class Person {
    String name;
    Person parent;
    Person child;    
    Person (String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Person parent = new Person("John");
    parent.child = new Person("Snow");
    parent.child.parent = parent;
    Person child = parent.child;
    parent = null;
    child = null;
    System.out.println("finished");
}
```

Comment: The GC is a lot smarter than you give it credit for.

Answer (score -1):

If there are no other reference to any of these objects, yes, they can be collected.